# Connecting Roland drums to Ableton Live

Tags: ableton-live, electronic-drumset

This is the first time I have tried to use electronic drums through Ableton Live. I use a Focusrite Scarlett interface for other instruments so I am assuming that I will need to do the same for the electronic drums (Roland TD-11). This  means finding a cable with a USB type B at one end and a jack plug at the other. Do such cables exist or could I connect straight into the back of the computer? Other people must have had this challenge, any help is gratefully received.

Comment: Do you want to record the TD-11's audio output, or the drum hits as MIDI data for triggering a soft synth or sampler in Ableton? You can get both audio and MIDI to your computer from the TD-11's USB connector, but if you want to record audio from the Focusrite Scarlett at the same time, then you'll want to get the TD-11 as MIDI only... or bring in the TD-11's audio as audio through the Scarlett. Ableton can only input audio from one device at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect direct via usb lead to your computer from your TD11. I've just started this but have now stumbled across the issue of additional latency (compared to my existing minilab midi controller) and it not have a 'v drums' allocation in the midi control interface when in the 'link midi' preferences. Good luck